# Команды DOS в Delphi

Tags: dos, delphi

Как вызвать команду DOS из программы Delphi?

Answer (score 3):

Варианты: CreateProcess или ShellExecute. Пример (без обработки исключений):

```
function RunCommand(command: string; waitable: bool) : bool;
  var
    si : TStartupInfo;
    pi : TProcessInformation;
  begin
      ZeroMemory(@si, SizeOf(si));
      si.cb := SizeOf(si);
      Result = CreateProcess(nil, PChar(command), nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil, si, pi) 
      CloseHandle(pi.hThread); 
      if waitable = true 
          then WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
      CloseHandle(pi.hProcess)
  end;
```

command - это командная строка, которую нужно выполнить.